# How to get the Modal effect using react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-modal

I am trying to replicate Popup behaviour(Modal) using react-navigation. I am able to replicate some parts of it but I am not able to generate the complete result. I have to put the tabBar in the Background of the screen. I don't want to hide it. I am using Navigation it gives me some significant advantages over Modal.

I have tried using `tabBarVisible: false` but it hides the tabBar completely. I am using `mode: 'modal'` to have the modal behaviour and using TouchableHighlight to close the Modal if pressed on the empty part of the screen. I am not able to overlap the tabBar like the images I have attached below.

This is my code:

```
const SpaceTabNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Spaces: {
    screen: SpacesTab
  },
  applianceList: AppliancesList,
  applianceConfig: ApplianceConfig
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Spaces',
  headerMode: 'none',
  navigationOptions: {
      headerVisible: false,
  },
  mode: 'modal',
  transparentCard: true,
  cardStyle: {
    opacity: 1
  },
})

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Dashboard: {
    screen: HomeTab,
  },
  Spaces: SpaceTabNavigator,
  Moods: MoodStackNavigator,
},
{
  swipeEnabled: true,
  animationEnabled: true
})


const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    TabNav: TabNavigator
  },
  {
    contentComponent: Drawer
  }
);
```

Can you please suggest a way around it?

Here is the result I have achieved yet:  [The achieved Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yoDY.jpg)

Here is the result I want:  [This is the result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNjUM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Step - 1 : Make the modal transparent by using the 'transparent' prop from the modal.

Step - 2 : Give the modal margin bottom lets say 50 to render it above the tab bar.

This shall do it

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's a new screen with navigation. Is this possible in a screen to overlay the tabBar?

Comment: I don't think so. Why don't you use modal.

Comment: Because there are multiple calls on that screen which some corresponds to some specific parameters.  If I use Modal I'd have to figure which button was pressed to trigger that modal. Fortunately you can pass parameters in navigation which makes it easier for me to control those calls.